# How to send the output to a file in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How can I send the output from Xquery to an xml file

Comment: How do you plan to execute it?  What engine are you using?

Comment: An XQuery implementation only may support the [Serialization Feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-serialization-feature), but if it does the serialization process is described in [XSLT 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/) and in the section [Serialization Parameters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-xq-serialization-parameters). From all that you may notice that there isn't a machanism to define the URI for the outcomming document as there is in [XSLT 2.0 Creating Final Result Trees](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what processor you're using.  Usually this is defined from outside the query from the calling program or command line.  For example, if you're using Saxon, you can use the -o command line parameter to specify an output file. See: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.xml

Comment: Is there any way to do it inside the structure FLWOR

Comment: No, if I'm understanding your question, you have to define the final destination of an xquery from outside the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

Zorba provides a file module for this: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-1.4.0/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_file.html